# Inserting a 3D cube in a video frame

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

In my code I have a 3d cube which i draw using following snippet:

```
ver = [0 0 0; 0 1 0; 1 1 0; 1 0 0; 0 0 1; 0 1 1; 1 1 1; 1 0 1];
face = [1 2 3 4; 2 6 7 3; 4 3 7 8; 1 5 8 4; 1 2 6 5; 5 6 7 8];
patch('Vertices',ver,'Faces',face,'FaceVertexCData',hsv(6),'FaceColor','flat');
```

I have video which I am processing frame by frame:

```
videoFile = vision.VideoFileReader(filename);   
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer();
frame = step(videoFile);
```

I want to draw/insert the cube in this video frame. How is it possible in matlab. Thanks

Comment: What Matlab version are you using?

Comment: I am using MATLAB 2013a

Comment: you mean read a video file and embed the cube inside each frame? do you want it in a fixed place or somthing like augmented reality?

Comment: @Mercury Actually its a part of augmented reality. The cube is doing fine with respect to the reality (projection etc) but I have these two things displaying separately. I want to stitch them together in one frame.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot use MATLAB graphics objects, such as a patch, in `vision.VideoPlayer`.  `vision.VideoPlayer` can only display images, so if you want to overlay graphics onto an image you have to draw directly into the pixels.  Try using the `insertShape` function.